# problem with two versions of python

Tags: python, jupyter, numpy

I'm new to python and  ubuntu. I installed two versions of python to be able to use them in jupyter .. but when i checked the version of numpy i got

```
python
import numpy 
numpy.__version__
```

and got

```
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.14.5'
```

but when i used

```
pip show numpy
Name: numpy
Version: 1.11.0
Summary: NumPy: array processing for numbers, strings, records, and 
objects.
Home-page: http://www.numpy.org
Author: NumPy Developers
Author-email: numpy-discussion@scipy.org
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

and the

```
 python3 -m pip --version
 pip --version
```

got

```
 pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip (python 3.4)
```

and

```
 python -m pip --version
```

got

```
 pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

now i'm confusing with both versions . i got error with

```
slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

and found that because i need to downgrade numpy but i found two and don't know which one i should use ?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the `pip` command directly, because it's ambiguous which instance of the Python package manager this command is referring to under some circumstances. I think it will be the one you installed/upgraded last.

You should preferably call it as a Python module instead, like one of these, depending on whether you want `pip` for Python 2 or 3:

```
python -m pip
python3 -m pip
```

That way you can always be sure you get the package manager for the right Python installation you want.

To e.g. install `numpy` for Python 3, you would now run

```
python3 -m pip install numpy
```

Comment: thanks for replying , but do you mean like that python -m pip numpy ?

Comment: Instead of `pip install numpy` you would now say `python -m pip install numpy` (or `python3 -m pip install numpy`). Basically all you do is prefixing your "traditional" `pip` command with `python -m`/`python3 -m`.